# Uncheck the checkbox while checking another

Tags: jquery

I have this code but it just doesn't work. It works at the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MQM8k/)  but when I try to run it from my site it doens't work?

here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test checkbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$('input.example').on('change', function() {
    $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either put the script under the inputs, or use a document.ready function (which in jquery is as simple as `$( ... );` I believe

Comment: Have you considered using a radio button?

Comment: Your example code here is also missing jQuery altogether, you only have jQuery UI (twice).

Comment: Remove all the scripts just leave jquery. If it works add one of your scripts. Do it until you find what script breaks it and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test checkbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$('input.example').on('change', function() {
    $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Move your javascript code because when the JS is executed your input doesn't exists yet.

Otherwise you can add $(document).ready function to wait the page load ending before executing js code  like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test checkbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.example').on('change', function() {
            $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
        });
    });</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, i hope you understood your error, its the main thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the JS when the document is ready not earlier.
Also there is no point loading jquery-ui.js and jquery-uy.min.js.
You need to load jquery first and then jquery-ui(if you need it).

For my bellow example I assume that js/1.9.2/jquery.js exists.

Try this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test checkbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.example').on('change', function() {
        $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
<input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</body>
```

Comment: I tried with this code but it still doesn't work and yes the two jquery file is in the folder js/1.9.2/

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.example').on('change', function() {
            $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
        });
    });
```

I think you doesn't need `<script src="js/1.9.2/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>`
for this script to work :)